# LinkedList and iterator

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

This is my class (it contain a lot more methode but for the problem its enough):

```
public class EntrepotChaineeImpl<T extends NombreExemplaires> implements EntrepotTda<T> {

private Node<T> head;
private Node<T> tail;
private int places;
private int maxPlaces;

public EntrepotChaineeImpl(int nbPlacesMaximum) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    head= null;
    tail = null;
    this.maxPlaces = maxPlaces;
    places= 0;

}

@Override
public Iterateur<T> iterator() {
    // TODO
    return new Iterateur();
}

private final class Iterateur<T extends NombreExemplaires> implements Iterator<T>{

    private Node<T> aNode;

    public Iterateur(){
        aNode = head;  //<---THE ERROR
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Iterator.super.remove();
    }

}
```

The problem is, i get this error on the constructor of Iterrateur:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Node T extends NombreExemplaires  to Node T extends NombreExemplaires

I realy dont see why. thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner class `Iterateur` is not `static`, which means that type parameters declared on the enclosing class `EntrepotChaineeImpl` (`T`) are in scope.

You don't need to re-declare `T` on `Iterateur`; this defines another `T` that is different from `EntrepotChaineeImpl`'s `T`.  Because `T` is still in scope, you can just use it in the `implements` clause.

```
private final class Iterateur implements Iterator<T>{
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private final class Iterateur<T extends NombreExemplaires> implements Iterator<T>{
```

should be

```
private final class Iterateur implements Iterator<T>{
```

Right now you have two different type variables named `T`, one shadowing the other.